# How to properly include research papers that are still not published in a curriculum vitae?

Tags: publications, cv, research-undergraduate

I'm currently working on two research papers that I will send in a month to a peer-review journal, but I need to write my CV right now to apply for a job.

In my CV there are currently three sections:

- Refereed Journal Articles
- Refereed Conference Papers
- Other scientific publication [where I've included some non-refereed publications]

In your opinion, what is the best title for a section about the two papers I'm currently working on, which are going to be submitted to peer-review journals soon, but are currently in progress?

Answer (score 2):

*Work in Progress* is good and it  is good to have such a section.

You can also annotate each paper title with the expected time to (or of) submission. "Submission expected in December 2020", for example.

Comment: "Submission expected in December 2020" ... or perhaps even better, "can be ready to submit with approximately n weeks' full-time equivalent work", so that if your new employer delays submission by loading you up with non-research tasks, you're not the one who's over-promised and under-delivered.